# Laravel store() method from api controller not returning updated data

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm having an issue where the store method in my `UserCountries` API controller is returning data that seems to be one step behind and I'm not sure why. My app has two models: `Country` and `User`, which have a many-to-many relationship with a pivot table. In my app a particular user should be able to 'like' and 'unlike' a country.

This mostly works as expected, however my issue is that the data returned on each request is one step behind - e.g., if I send a `POST` request to like a particular country, I get a `200` response but I am returned a `UserCountriesResource` which does not include that country that should have just been added. If I then immeditaely send a `GET` request, it returns a `UserCountriesResource` which *does* include that country. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Here are my routes:

```
    Route::group(["prefix" => "me/countries"], function(){
        Route::get("", [UserCountries::class, "index"]); // see all countries liked by user
        Route::post("", [UserCountries::class, "store"]); // add or remove country from user
    });
```

My index method in the UserCountries controller is below:

```
    public function index()
    {
        return CountryResource::collection(auth()->user()->countries);
    }
```

My store method in the UserCountries controller is below:

```
    public function store(UserCountriesRequest $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->setCountries($request->get("countries"));
        return new UserCountriesResource($user);
    }
```

The store method calls the `setCountries` method in the User model:

```
    public function setCountries(array $strings) : User
    {
        $countries = Country::fromStrings($strings);
        $countries->map(function($country) use($countries){
            if($this->countries->contains($country)){
                Country::find($country->id)->users()->detach($this->id);
            } else {
                $this->countries()->syncWithoutDetaching($country->id);
            }
        });
        return $this;
    }
```

The setCountries method above in turn calls the `fromStrings` method in the Country model:

```
    public static function fromStrings(array $strings) : Collection
    {
        return collect($strings)->map(fn($str) => trim($str))
            ->unique()
            ->map(fn($str) => Country::firstOrCreate(["NAME"=>$str]));
    }
```

Do let me know if there's anything else I can add to make this more helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the relationship before you are adding/removing any of the related records. That loaded relationship, Collection, won't include these changes. You will need to reload the relationship to get the new list of related records.

I don't know the rest of your code but you would add a call like this, if this was the case:

```
$user->load('countries');
```

This is loading the relationship (if it wasn't already loaded):

```
if($this->countries->contains($country))
```

Comment: Fantastic, I added `$user->load('countries');` to my `store()` method and that seems to have solved i! Thank you very much